# WPF Data Grid

Tags: wpf, datagrid

How to disable datagrid cell edit?

Answer (score 2):

The DataGrid columns (like DataGridTextColumn) have an IsReadOnly property, just set it to "True".

```
<tk:DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=MyData}" Header="My header" />
```

Comment: A bit simpler than what I suggested! Am I right in thinking the ReadOnly columns weren't in the CTP of the DataGrid control when it came out last year? Seems I need to refresh my knowledge.

Comment: Right, IsReadOnly was not in the early releases of the DataGrid.  I forget exactly when it was added.